# Unable to open/read XML file containing accented characters

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML attribute that containers an accent characters:

```
 <TestCase Name="Canadian Addresses - Test Case" Description="Canadian Addresses - Test Case" OnOff="True" NegativeTest="False" RollbackDB="False" Performance="False" PerformanceSummary="False" TimesToExecute="1">

 <ProviderFacilitySearch_FindProviderFacility ProviderInfo="Dr Marc-André Kärcher Samuels Senior|10 Château du Feÿ Ave, North Building, North Sydney, NS  B2A 3L7 CANADA" />
 <ProviderFacilitySearch_ViewProviderFacility ProviderInfo="Dr Marc-André Kärcher Samuels Senior|10 Château du Feÿ Ave, North Building, North Sydney, NS  B2A 3L7 CANADA" />
 <ViewProvider_LocationName ExpectedLocationName="Kärcher Health Care" />
 <ViewProvider_ServicingAddress ExpectedServicingAddress="10 Château du Feÿ Ave|Central Building|North Sydney, NS  B2A 3L7|CANADA" />
 <ViewProvider_ExpandMailingAddress NA="" />
 <ViewProvider_MailingAddress ExpectedMailingAddress="10 Château du Feÿ Ave|Central Building|North Sydney, NS  B2A 3L7|CANADA" />
 <ViewProvider_ExpandBillingAddress NA="" />
 <ViewProvider_BillingAddress ExpectedBillingAddress="10 Château du Feÿ Ave|Central Building|North Sydney, NS  B2A 3L7|CANADA" />
 <ViewProvider_Close NA="" />
 <ProviderFacilitySearch_Cancel NA="" />
 <UserLogout/>
 </TestCase>
```

When I try to read this XML file using C# code, I'm getting:

> 5/8/2013 2:39:03 PM ERROR: System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 86, position 74.
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
>      at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)

I can't even open the page using IE.

Is there a way to get this work?

Comment: Sounds like your XML file is broken - I suspect it declares one encoding, but has been written with a different one. You haven't told us anything about where the file came from, so it's hard to give any more information than that - but don't try to work around the problem; fix it so that you've got a valid XML file to start with.

Comment: What xml encoding are you using? ISO 8859-1 will fail on some of the accented characters, while UTF-8 shouldn't.

Comment: Could you post the header of the XML file?  That should say what encoding it thinks it's working with.

Comment: Someone has been creating XML files without using XML APIs. Using string concatenation, maybe?

Comment: The XML file was created to driver test automation as a data driven file.  The header of the XML is as follows-                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>

Comment: Here is the C# code that hits the error:          XDocument xmlTestCaseDoc = null; 
xmlTestCaseDoc = XDocument.Load(testFile);

Comment: The accented characters do NOT show when setting the encoding in Notepad++ to UTF-8.  I just wanted to add this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this header:

```
<?XML VERSION='1.0' ENCODING='ISO-8859-1'?>
```

Edit

The encoding declaration identifies which encoding is used to represent the characters in the XML document. Although XML parsers can determine automatically if a document uses the UTF-8 or UTF-16 Unicode encoding, this declaration should be used in documents that support other encodings.

Comment: Why? An answer should explain how it helps to solve the question

Comment: ok, thaks you Mark,we should't just solve their problems, we must help them to understand how it works, will improve the answer and will keep that in mind for the next one.

Comment: @erman8 if this fixes your problem, please consider marking Logar314159's answer as "Accepted".  Cheers.

Comment: With a SQL Server generated file, I had better result using `ENCODING='windows-1252'`

Answer (score 0):

To see if the file is actually encoded the way its header says it is, use a hex reader (e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) to see the stored bytes.

If the file is UTF8, you should see something similar to this:

```
(...)  ProviderInfo="Dr Marc-AndrÃ© KÃ¤rcher Samuels Senior|10 ChÃ¢teau du FeÃ¿ Ave (...)
```